# jinja2 form render does not allow attribute which contains "-"

Tags: google-app-engine, django-forms, jinja2

I am trying to customize the form template base on [this tutorial](http://kay-docs.shehas.net/forms-usage.html#customizing-the-form-template).  As I understand, `render()` just add some attributes to the tag. For example, I add `placeholder = "abc"` and it works well.

```
{% call inserttourbus(id = "formAddNewRow" )  %}

     <div class="fieldWrapper">
         {% if inserttourbus['bustype'].label() %}Bus Type{% endif %}
         {{ inserttourbus['bustype'].render(placeholder="abc")|safe }}
         {% if inserttourbus['bustype'].errors() %}Not filled yet!{% endif %}      
     </div>
{% endcall %}
```

Here is my problem:
- I use `bootstrap typeahead` for my template so I need to add the following attribute to the `inserttourbus` textbox

```
data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Alabama","Alaska"]'
```

So it will become

```
{{ inserttourbus['bustype'].render(placeholder="abc", data-provide="typeahead", data-items="4", data-source='["Alabama","Alaska"]')|safe }}
```

But the jinja2 engine seems does not accept `data-provide`, `data-items`, so on because it contain `"-"` character. If I changed `data-provide` to `dataprovide`, the jinja2 engine can render the code well.

However, in `bootstrap typeahead` javascript, all variables are defined as `data-provide`, `data-items`. If I change them to `dataprovide`, `dataitems`, the javascipt stop working.

Please give me a solution:
- How to make jinja2 accept attribute which has "-"
- Other solutions, advices

Answer (score 9):

Check out [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/107/) for doing this in Flask. I imagine it would work the same way for Django; pass HTML attributes with invalid Jinja2 (Python) syntax inside an ad-hoc dictionary:

```
{{ inserttourbus['bustype'].render(placeholder="abc", 
       **{'data-provide':'typeahead',
          'data-items':'4',
          'data-source':'["Alabama","Alaska"]'}) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Hyphen is used as the subtraction operator in Python. So do not use it in names. You can use it ofcourse in strings.

Comment: i change data-provide to data u'\N{HYPHEN-MINUS}'provide, but it does not work